# How to take screenshot of obscured window in C++ on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, screenshot, x11

I'm trying to figure out how to take a screenshot of a window that is currently not focused, so there is a good chance that the window will be partially or fully obscured by other windows.

I've found an example here on this link [Get a screenshot of a window that is cover or not visible or minimized with Xcomposite extension for X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512177/get-a-screenshot-of-a-window-that-is-cover-or-not-visible-or-minimized-with-xcom) but I can't make it work, any time I take a screenshot I get only strange output, mostly black, like I'm accessing the wrong buffer or something.

```
  XID xid = windowID;  // Checked and confirmed that the window ID is correct
  XGetWindowAttributes( display, windowID, &attrributes );

  XCompositeRedirectWindow (display, xid, CompositeRedirectAutomatic);

  Pixmap pixmap = XCompositeNameWindowPixmap (display, xid);

  // Extract the data
  XRenderPictFormat *format = XRenderFindVisualFormat (display, attrributes.visual);

  XRenderPictureAttributes pa;
  pa.subwindow_mode = IncludeInferiors;
  Picture picture = XRenderCreatePicture (display, xid, format, CPSubwindowMode, &pa);

  QPixmap finalPix (attrributes.width, attrributes.height);
  XRenderComposite (display, PictOpSrc, picture, None, finalPix.x11PictureHandle(), 0,0, 0,0, 0,0, attrributes.width, attrributes.height);

  XFreePixmap (display, pixmap);
  XCompositeUnredirectWindow (display, xid, CompositeRedirectAutomatic);

  return finalPix;
```

**(Edit:** *This screenshot was taken from a fully visible window, not an obscured window, so I guess currently the issue is not even that X11 doesn't draw it but my implementation seems to be not working and I can't figure out why.*)
And this is how a screenshot of my konsole window looks:

[image: The resulting screenshot]

Comment: It looks like I'm not copping anything into the QPixmap. When I create an empty QPixmap with some size I get the same output...

Answer (score 3):

First of all Qt has this feature. You can use: [QScreen::grabWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow).
Problem is that documentation says:

> Note on X11 that if the given window doesn't have the same depth as
>   the root window, and another window partially or entirely obscures the
>   one you grab, you will not get pixels from the overlying window. The
>   contents of the obscured areas in the pixmap will be undefined and
>   uninitialized.

So this will simplify your code, but obscured parts of window will still remains as a problem. Looks like functionality of x11 won't let to resolve this issue.

There is a good example [how to use this feature](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out though I believe this function was introduced in  Qt5.0 and I'm using 4.8. Further, it doesn't resolve my primary issue, which is that I can't capture obscured windows or frames. 

Just a screenshot from a window that is visible is not a problem, I have the WId and from there I get the window attributes like window position and size and they I just grab a rect at that position, that is not a problem.

I'm not sure if this is actually doable with X11 or do I have to use something else...

Comment: This actually doesn't answer my question at all. I'm looking for a solution to take a screenshot of an obscured window and the answer says that this is not possible with this solution, so totally misleading "_The contents of the obscured areas in the pixmap will be undefined and uninitialized._".