# How to capture the current screen image using Qt?

Tags: qt

I have a button in my Custom QDialog, I am emitting a signal when pushbutton 1 is clicked

```
void MyCustomDialog::on_pushButton_1()
{
    this->hide(); //i need to hide this window before 'OnButton_1_Clicked' stuffs starts
    emit button_1_clicked();
}
```

In my main window I have connected the slot and created the instance as shown below

```
void MainWindow::MainWindow()
{

    MyCustomDialog *dlg = MyCustomDialog::getInstance(this); //only single instance created
    connect(dlg, &MyCustomDialog::button_1_clicked, this, &MainWindow::OnButton_1_Clicked);
}
```

I am displaying my custom dialog from a function in mainwindow as below

```
void MainWindow::dispayCustomDialog()
{
    MyCustomDialog *dlg = MyCustomDialog::getInstance();
    dlg->show();
}
```

Below shows how my 'OnButton_1_Clicked' slot. In which I am capturing the screenshot using below line

```
void MainWindow::OnButton_1_Clicked()
{
     //capture the screen shot
     QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
     QPixmap *map = new QPixmap(screen->grabWindow(0));
     bool result = map->save("D:/test.jpg", "JPG");
}
```

Once I captured screen using above function, I can still see my 'MyCustomDialog' in test.jpg file.  Qt doc says `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen` captures the initial state of application. So i think, this is expected in my case. Do we have any other solution to grab screen with current state ?

What I am trying to achieve is grab the screen in OnButton_1_Clicked() function after hiding my 'MyCustomDialog'.

Comment: How do you know it is executed before closing?, 
I just tried it and it works correctly. 
To do this, verify if it was hidden: `void MainWindow::OnButton_1_Clicked()
{
    qDebug()<< MyCustomDialog::getInstance()->isVisible();
    qDebug()<<"clicked";
}` 
and I get: `false
clicked`. 
the connection using Qt::QueuedConnection is unnecessary, that flag must be activated if the connection is between 2 objects that are in 2 different threads.

Comment: Oh. my bad. You are right. I should have been verified with visible function.  Unfortunately, I verified with grabbing the screen in 'OnButton_1_Clicked()'. So the mistake was in my grabing screen function.  `QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QPixmap *map = new QPixmap(screen->grabWindow(0));
    bool result = map->save("D:/screen.jpg", "JPG");`.

Comment: As I understand the `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();` captures the initial state of the screen in which my custom dialog was visible initially.

Comment: So, I should have to find another way to capture current screen instead of intial screen by `QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()`.

Comment: You have a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), 
Your question should focus on your main objective, and not on solving a possible solution that is not certain to work.

Comment: Edit your question and add all the detail

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc, sorry for the XY problem and your time.  I have edited the question. Please see the same

Comment: @eyllanesc, i am developing for both windows and linux. Currently developing with Win10

Comment: For Linux is a problem, check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984092/how-to-take-screenshot-of-obscured-window-in-c-on-linux

Comment: what about windows ?

Comment: Try the following example and check if it works: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html

Comment: @eyllanesc, I found a solution from the your provided example doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html.  Used a singleshot timer before grabing the screen. It waits to close my custom dialog properly

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank you for your example

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Used a singleslot timer with delay of 500 msec before capturing the screen as below. This wait for my custom dialog to hide properly.

```
void MainWindow::OnButton_1_Clicked()
{
     QTimer::singleShot(500, this, &MainWindow::shootscreen);
}

void MainWindow::shootscreen()
{
     //capture the screen shot
     QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
     QPixmap map = screen->grabWindow(0);
     bool result = map.save("D:/test.jpg", "JPG");
}
```

Comment: Do not use a pointer, you are creating dynamic memory that you do not eliminate, that is bad practice. Change it to: `QPixmap map =screen->grabWindow(0);
     bool result = map.save("D:/test.jpg", "JPG");`